# oracle forms 10g web application

Tags: plsql, oracleforms

I'm working in oracle forms 10g.

I write message in when new form instance trigger it did not show 
when I run the form from application but when I run it from form builder directly 
then it shows message. I want to see message when i open form from application?

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Hi Imran, welcome to SO. If you take a little tour of the questions asked and well answered here, you'll see it is better to post the parts of the code you think must be improved.
Take your time to format and rephrase your question please; read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: The application message level is probably higher and won't let you see your message

Answer (score 0):

The message probably is showing in the bottom left corner.

Instead of

```
message ('Your message goes here');
```

use

```
message ('Your message goes here');
pause;
```

The `pause` command should make sure it pops up when you open the form and not just show it at the bottom.